# Applications using the .Net ramework 2.0 are not working on Windows 7

Tags: .net, windows, windows-7, operating-system

I am running into problems with Windows 7, applications using the .Net Framework 2.0 are not running.  I know that I cannot install 2.0 from net as it is shipped with OS.

I tried to enable (ON) .Net framework 3.5 from Windows feature but it didn't help.  A message appears that not all feature were completed in success. When I expand Microsoft .Net framework 3.5 there are only two items Wndows Communication Foundation HTTP Activation and Windows Communication Foundation Non HTTP Activation. There is no .Net framework 2.0 or any other listed there.

Can any body here help me - how can I enable/install .Net framework 2.0 or 3.5.

Comment: The 2.0 runtime would already exist on the machine. What exactly isn't working?

Comment: applications, for examplepe Nunit with .net framwork 2.0, while it works when i select runtime 4.0

Answer (score 2):

Don't assume that any operating system has *any* version of the .Net framework installed [Windows is not a .NET Framework delivery channel](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/04/04/10149346.aspx)

It sounds like your .Net 2.0 installation is either broken or missing. Try uninstalling and then re-installing it again and if it fails pay attention to any error messages and post them here*

(*) I'm assuming that this question will be migrated to either super user or server fault.

Comment: Thanks Justin, From contol panel->Programs and Features-> Turn Windows feature NO or OFF, and check the .net framework 3.5.1 but an error message got "An error has occured. Not all features has successfully changed " and then to restart computer. After restart I tried to run NUnit 2.5.10, and message "Nunit has stopped working. Winows is checking for a solution to problem....."  similar message I got when I run other programs like IHE-RO,a tool for testing medical domain apps.